# WooCommerce change order number based on product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, cart

I have products in 6 different main categories.
What I want is to modify the order number based on the category of the products in cart. It needs to pick the category of the first product appearing in the cart. Based on this category I want to add this function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {

    $prefix = 'AB-';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;

}
```

So basically I want to make an if else statement in this function for example:

```
if ('category of first product in appearing in cart' === 'category id / category name') {

    $prefix = 'AB-';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;

}
elseif ('category of first product in appearing in cart' === 'category id / category name') {

    $prefix = 'CD-';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;

}
elseif ('category of first product in appearing in cart' === 'category id / category name') {

    $prefix = 'EF-';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;

}
```

Problem now is that I need to get the category id / category name of the first product appearing in the cart. How can I get that in my functions.php file?

Comment: where you want to show category name?

Comment: On the review-order.php 
So based on what it says there I can implement this function.